# How can I download specific dev version of Drupal module?

Tags: 7, drush, version-control

What to do when I want specific dev version of Drupal module.

For example:

Geocoder dev version from Jan 07 2016 is [broken](https://www.drupal.org/node/2647536). Latest working dev version was from Sept 01 2015.

How can I download previous dev version of Drupal module ([Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder) in my case)? Any method is welcome.

Comment: Why do you need to do it via Drush? Is it just a case or is it really important?

Comment: @Eugene Any method welcome (I have updated my question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the easiest way to do it:

1. Go into the [repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/geocoder/log/)
2. Select a version there and click on it
3. There will be hash of commit ([example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/geocoder/commit/?id=c994066d58bc7518bc9796c60d4d43f98ae477cd))

So, you know the hash of commit - just clone this module from repository and switch to required hash of commit.

How to [clone module via git](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder/git-instructions)

How to [checkout the specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo)

Example:

```
git clone --branch 7.x-1.x https://git.drupal.org/project/geocoder.git
cd geocoder
git checkout c994066d58bc7518bc9796c60d4d43f98ae477cd
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one more way how to download specific dev version of Drupal module:

**“Drush make” method**

Create make file for Drush (for example `myMakeFile.make`) and paste into it following:

```
api = 2
core = 7.x
projects[drupal][version] = 7.30
projects[geocoder][version] = "1.x-dev"
projects[geocoder][download][type] = "git"
projects[geocoder][download][url] = "https://git.drupal.org/project/geocoder.git"
projects[geocoder][download][revision] = "2ffd3fa8b22c11100516bf801bc08ba729cc8a68"
```

Type into shell:

```
cd
mkdir removeMeWhenDone
mv myMakeFile.make removeMeWhenDone
cd removeMeWhenDone
drush make myMakeFile.make -y
```

Desired dev version of the Geocoder module is located in `~/removeMeWhenDone/sites/all/modules`, now.

More details about *Drush make* method + how to get commit hash [here](http://www.jasom.net/how-to-download-specific-dev-version-of-drupal-module-simply-using-git-checkout-or-drush-make).